# How to Get AWS Glue Client in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to invoke a Job in AWS Glue from my Lambda code written in Java.
But I am not able to get the Glue Client.

Like we have DynamoClient like this -

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1").build();
```

What would be the equivalent for Glue Client ?

```
AWSGlueClient glue = null; // how to instantiate client
StartJobRunRequest jobRunRequest = new StartJobRunRequest();
jobRunRequest.setJobName("TestJob");
StartJobRunResult jobRunResult = glue.startJobRun(jobRunRequest);
```

I am not seeing the AmazonGlueClientBuilder class.
As I am new to glue, please let me know if I am doing it wrong or it there any other way I can use to invoke the glue job.

Also I am using the following Maven Dependency -

```
<dependency>            
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-glue</artifactId>
   <version>1.11.289</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent would be

```
AWSGlueClient.builder().withRegion("us-east-1").build()
```

Comment: With Region is not supported in Glue.

Comment: @devutkarsh Are you sure? It is listed in the Javadoc here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/glue/AWSGlueClientBuilder.html

Comment: I tried using the syntax that you provided in answer. The builder does not takes .withRegion.

Comment: I just tried it locally with the version you provide and does indeed work, so probably something is not correctly added to the classpath. Can Maven at least resolve the symbol AWSGlueClient?

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet along with imports and dependencies ?

Comment: The dependency is the same as the one you are using in the answer. The import is just `import com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient;` and then the snippet in he answer

Answer (score 1):

If your lambda is in the same region as Glue resources then simply use

```
AWSGlue glueClient = AWSGlueClientBuilder.defaultClient()
```

Answer (score 0):

Most AWS Java SDK client 'builders' follow the below convention:

*ServiceName* serviceName = *ServiceName*ClientBuilder.standard()/default()...

There is one Glue 'instance' available per-account, per-region so something along the following lines should get you up and running.

```
AWSGlue awsGlueClient =
    AWSGlueClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue Client initalization and sample use in Java:

```
    AWSGlue glueClient = AWSGlueClient.builder().withRegion("us-east-1").build();
    StartJobRunRequest job = new StartJobRunRequest();
    job.setJobName("ETLJob");
    StartJobRunResult jobResult = glueClient.startJobRun(job);
```