# How to call AWS Glue crawler from AWS Glue job using Scala API?

Tags: scala, aws-glue, glue-crawler

I want to call GlueCrawler from the Glue job. I see there is an API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling-StartCrawler
But I totally lost how I can call it? I can't find examples in internet as well. I found some Python samples using boto3 and it is working fine, but I need scala call. 
If I understand correctly, I need some how instantiate GlueClient and call startCrawler operation on it, but how to do it? All examples that I found operates only on GlueContext and it is not clear how to retrieve GlueClient from it(if it is possible at all?).

Answer (score 1):

I haven´t workded with glue, but looks like there is a [JDK SDK for glue with some examples of how to start a crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/java_2_glue_code_examples.html). One of them, shows how to start a crawler, but as you said the `GlueClient` is provided. Based on the thread [How to Get AWS Glue Client in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49400946/how-to-get-aws-glue-client-in-java), you should be able to create an instance of the client doing something like

```
AWSGlueClient.builder().withRegion("us-east-1").build()
```

[The API Doc of GlueClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/glue/GlueClient.html) shows that the it should be possible to do that.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. It was not full answer but it is helped. Main problem was that I used some wrong example and wrong imports.. And AWSGlueClient was not visible.